Docker network issues when using profiles
I have the following docker network:
services:
  service:
    build:
      context: ../service
      dockerfile: ../service/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  database:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    ports:
      - "14333:1433"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    command: /bin/bash -c "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"

  init-db:
    profiles: [initdb]
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools:latest
    build:
      context: ../database
      dockerfile: ./initdb.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:

It contains the following services:

database: which is a SQL database
service: a golang REST API, which utilizes the database (this connects successfully)
init-db: a script that needs to be occasionally run to seed the database, consists of some shell scripts

My flow for setting up docker network consists of two commands these are run sequentially:
docker compose up

This successfully spins up service and database services and I can see in the logs that the connection between them is successful
Then I run:
docker compose --profile initdb up --build

Info on profiles: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/15-profiles/?highlight=profiles
This runs a bunch of shell scripts, in these scripts I try to ping the database container on host database however it says host not found.
Additionally, while this initdb profile is running if I inspect the network I can only see the service and database services, which explains the conenctivity issues.
docker network inspect  local-infra_mynetwork

[
    {
        "Name": "local-infra_mynetwork",
        "Id": "",
        "Created": "2024-06-14T15:00:30.235377615Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.0.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "358112012d019169748da32bf20e2bd73b8c714408c58ae4dfec88a48d2892d4": {
                "Name": "local-infra-service-1",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.3/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "952e3c1e4bb0f57f132d1f88738e5f08a52dfcf2715f4e2027a1147ce73b559e": {
                "Name": "local-infra-database-1",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.2/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "mynetwork",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "local-infra",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.27.0"
        }
    }
]


I would expect that the init-db service would be present in mynetwork as it clearly has it defined in the docker-compose.yml
Question

Is this connectivity problem a result of using profiles and excuting these routines seperately?

Or is it to do with the fact that init-db isnt a continually running service like service and database?

Or something to do with my docker network?



When you run docker compose up and docker compose --profile initdb up --build separately, the containers are not part of the same lifecycle and do not share the same network state at runtime. This causes the init-db container to not see the database container because they are not up and running at the same time in the same network context.
Removing the profiles block from the init-db service solved my issue.
